# Разграничение падежей

Tags: синтаксис

Мой вопрос связан с разграничением родительного и винительного падежей, а именно в тех ситуациях, когда не ясно, какой именно вопрос нужно задать. Приведу пару примеров и сразу скажу, что речь именно о единственном числе:
1) Я жду его назначение(ия). То есть - жду (чего?) назначения или жду (что?) назначение?
2) ни разу не встречала исключение(ия). Не встречала (что?) исключение или не встречала (чего?) исключения?
Пожалуйста, если можно, то дайте ответ со ссылкой на конкретное правило. Либо какой-то способ, который позволит разграничить данные падежи. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на подобный вопрос от Грамоты.ru:

Глаголы ждать и ожидать могут управлять и родительным (кого-чего), и винительным (кого-что) падежом. Родительный падеж (ожидать чего, ждать чего) употребляется при сочетании с отвлеченными существительными или конкретными, но употребленными с оттенком неопределенности: *ждать возможности, ждать писем, ожидать прихода гостей, ожидать известий, ждать поезда* (какого-либо). Винительный падеж (ожидать что, ждать что) нужен при сочетании с одушевленными существительными или неодушевленными, но употребленными с оттенком определенности: *ждать сестру, ожидать поезд № 10*.

Я бы написал: *Я жду его назначения.*

С глаголом "встречать" словари отмечают только винительный падеж. Но, кажется, отрицательная частица "не" позволяет использовать родительный. Ведь, наверное, можно написать: "*Я ещё не встречал такого взгляда*" или "*Я ни разу не встречала исключения*". (Нужно ещё поисследовать эту тему...)

Вот ссылка о глаголах с отрицанием:  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr

Обратите внимание на последний раздел.

Answer (score 1):

Управление определяется некоторым набором правил, например,

> с глаголами достичь, жаждать, добиваться и домогаться существительные
>   согласуются в родительном падеже

но для каждого конкретного глагола их сформулировать нельзя. Следует руководствоваться справочниками, такими как справочник Д. Э. Розенталя "Управление в русском языке". В частности, по слову "ждать":

> ждать чего и кого-что.
>
> 1. чего (при сочетании с существительными отвлеченными или конкретными, но употребленными с оттенком неопределенности). Ждать
>      возможности. Ждать писем. Ждать поезда (какого-л.). Я ждал только
>      случая, чтобы показать ему, что нисколько не дорожу его обществом (Л.
>      Толстой).
> 2. кого-что (при сочетании с существительными одушевленными или существительными неодушевленными, употребленными с оттенком
>      определенности). Ждать сестру. Ждать ежедневную почту. Я жду одну
>      женщину (Тургенев). Ждать поезд Симферополь - Москва.